# xceed IntegerUpDown: shifted context menu values

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed

I use `Xceeed Wpf Toolkit` and `IntegerUpDown`:

```
 xmlns:XceedToolkit="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"

 <XceedToolkit:IntegerUpDown Grid.Column="1" Value="{Binding SelectedYear}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

But, when i do right click on this control, take this:

[image: xceed IntegerUpdown controlContextMenu]

If i make right click on anohter control like `TextBox` it is look normal.
Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: fix *what*? what is not normal here?

Comment: @ASh, fitst and third values are shifted right...

Comment: Somehow the `TextAlignment="Right"` from the control is spreading into the context menu even though it shouldn't (considering property values as presented by snoop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [WPF Textbox's TextAlignment changes its default context menu item's alignment as well](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/732a73d0-85fa-40e9-ad87-fb2c03452c75/wpf-textboxs-textalignment-changes-its-default-context-menu-items-alignment-as-well?forum=wpf), you have to rebuild the context menu, since the default can't be changed.

```
<XceedToolkit:IntegerUpDown>
    <XceedToolkit:IntegerUpDown.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left">
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" />
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" />
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" />
            </ContextMenu>
    </XceedToolkit:IntegerUpDown.ContextMenu>
</XceedToolkit:IntegerUpDown>
```

The issue is not specific to `XceedToolkit:IntegerUpDown` but applies to many controls with default context menu and `TextAlignment` property.

If you rather want to hack around with styles instead of replacing the context menu, your best bet for a target might be the `Popup`, since the context menu elements are internal classes somewhere, so creating a style for them won't work out of the box.

```
<XceedToolkit:IntegerUpDown>
    <xt:IntegerUpDown.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Popup">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        </Style>
    </xt:IntegerUpDown.Resources>
</xt:IntegerUpDown>
```